# heroku Nodejs app not unidling after request

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs app that runs on heroku and works fine until it idles(because im on the free plan). After it idles when I try to wake the app up it logs: "App Crashed". This issue is fixed by restarting the app using the cli: `heroku restart`. However this is not a working solution for the end user. I am using deploy through github and webpack, which I mention because those are the only differences from my other heroku apps which unidle just fine. Is there a way to have the request unidle the app?

Here are the logs:

```
2022-06-30T17:13:21.294071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-06-30T17:13:21.308560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-06-30T17:13:22.877570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-06-30T17:13:23.113129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-07-02T17:42:20.649030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fwpsg.herokuapp.com request_id=1f058e06-12e9-4210-a9bc-097ebdce811d fwd="73.247.37.113"
 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Are there any other logs above or below this block? More content may help us give a correct answer.

Comment: no, just the logs from the app working...

Comment: @JackAdee have you ever found a solution for your issue?

Comment: After a couple commits, it fixed itself.